# Get rid of the subqueries for the sake of sorting grouped data

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

### Tables

```
CREATE TABLE `aircrafts_in` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `city_from` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Откуда',
 `city_to` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Куда',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=91 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Самолёты по направлениям'

CREATE TABLE `aircrafts_in_parsed_data` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `price` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Ценник',
 `airline` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Авиакомпания',
 `date` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'Дата вылета',
 `info_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `info_id` (`info_id`),
 KEY `price` (`price`),
 KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=940682 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

date - departure date

```
CREATE TABLE `aircrafts_in_parsed_info` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `status` enum('success','error') DEFAULT NULL,
 `type` enum('roundtrip','oneway') NOT NULL,
 `date` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'Дата парсинга',
 `aircrafts_in_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ID направления',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `aircrafts_in_id` (`aircrafts_in_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=577759 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

date - created date, when was parsed

---

### Task

Get lowest price of ticket and date of departure for each month. Be aware that the minimum price is relevant, not just the minimum. If multiple dates with minimum cost, we need a first.

### My solution

I think that there's something not quite right.
**I don't like subqueries for grouping**, how to solve this problem

```
select *
from (
    select * from (
        select airline,
        price,
        pdata.`date` as `date`
        from aircrafts_in_parsed_data `pdata`
        inner join aircrafts_in_parsed_info `pinfo`
        on pdata.`info_id` = pinfo.`id`
        where pinfo.`aircrafts_in_id` = {$id}
            and pinfo.status = 'success'
            and pinfo.`type` = 'roundtrip'
            and `price` <> 0
        group by pdata.`date`, year(pinfo.`date`) desc, month(pinfo.`date`) desc, day(pinfo.`date`) desc
    ) base
    group by `date`
    order by price, year(`date`) desc, month(`date`) desc, day(`date`) asc
) minpriceperdate
group by year(`date`) desc, month(`date`) desc
```

Takes 0.015 s without cache, table size can view in auto increment

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  MIN(price) AS min_price,
        LEFT(date, 7) AS yyyy_mm
    FROM aircrafts_in_parsed_data
    GROUP BY LEFT(date, 7)
```

will get the lowest price for each month.  But it can't say 'first'.

From [my groupwise-max cheat-sheet](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max), I derive this:

```
SELECT
        yyyy_mm, date, price, airline  -- The desired columns
    FROM
      ( SELECT  @prev := '' ) init
    JOIN
      ( SELECT  LEFT(date, 7) != @prev  AS first,
                @prev := LEFT(date, 7)
                LEFT(date, 7) AS yyyy_mm, date, price, airline
            FROM  aircrafts_in_parsed_data
            ORDER BY
                LEFT(date, 7),   -- The 'GROUP BY'
                price ASC,       -- ASC to do "MIN()"
                date             -- To get the 'first' if there are dup prices for a month
      ) x
    WHERE  first           -- extract only the first of the lowest price for each month
    ORDER BY  yyyy_mm;     -- Whatever you like
```

Sorry, but subqueries are necessary.  (I avoided `YEAR()`, `MONTH()`, and `DAY()`.)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, your query is not correct.

Let's start with the innermost query: You group by pdata.date + pinfo.date, so you get one result row per date combination. As you don't specify which price or airline you are interested in for each date combination (such as `MAX(airline)` and `MIN(price)`), you get one airline arbitrarily chosen for a date combination and one price also arbitrarily chosen. These don't even have to belong to the same record in the table; the DBMS is free to chose one airline and one price matching the dates. Well, maybe the date combination of pdata.date and pinfo.date is already unique, but then you wouldn't have to group by at all. So however we look at this, this isn't proper.

In the next query you group by pdata.date only, thus again getting arbitrary matches for airline and price. You could have done that in the innermost query already. It makes no sense to say: "give me a randomly picked price per pdata.date and pinfo.date and from these give me a randomly picked price per pdata.date", you could just as well say it directly: "give me a randomly picked price per pdata.date". Then you order your result rows. This is completely useless, as you are using the results as a subquery (derived table) again, and such is considered an unordered set. So the `ORDER BY` gives the DBMS more work to do, but is in no way guaranteed to influence the main queries results.

In your main query then you group by year and month, again resulting in arbitrarily picked values.

Here is the same query a tad shorter and cleaner:

```
select 
  pdata.airline,  -- some arbitrily chosen airline matching year and month
  pdata.price,    -- some arbitrily chosen price matching year and month
  pdata.date      -- some arbitrily chosen date matching year and month
from aircrafts_in_parsed_data pdata
inner join aircrafts_in_parsed_info pinfo on pdata.info_id = pinfo.id
where pinfo.aircrafts_in_id = {$id}
and pinfo.status = 'success'
and pinfo.type = 'roundtrip'
and pdata.price <> 0
group by year(pdata.date), month(pdata.date)
order by year(pdata.date) desc, month(pdata.date) desc
```

As to the original task (as far as I understand it): Find the records with the lowest price per month. Per month means `GROUP BY` month. The lowest price is `MIN(price)`.

```
select
  min_price_record.departure_year,
  min_price_record.departure_month,
  min_price_record.min_price,
  full_record.departure_date,
  full_record.airline
from
(
  select 
    year(`date`) as departure_year, 
    month(`date`) as departure_month,
    min(price) as min_price
  from aircrafts_in_parsed_data
  where price <> 0
  and info_id in
  (
    select id
    from aircrafts_in_parsed_info
    where aircrafts_in_id = {$id}
    and status = 'success'
    and type = 'roundtrip'
  )
  group by year(`date`), month(`date`)
) min_price_record
join
(
  select 
    `date` as departure_date, 
    year(`date`) as departure_year, 
    month(`date`) as departure_month,
    price,
    airline
  from aircrafts_in_parsed_data
  where price <> 0
  and info_id in
  (
    select id
    from aircrafts_in_parsed_info
    where aircrafts_in_id = {$id}
    and status = 'success'
    and type = 'roundtrip'
  )
) full_record on full_record.departure_year = min_price_record.departure_year
              and full_record.departure_month = min_price_record.departure_month
              and full_record.price = min_price_record.min_price
order by 
  min_price_record.departure_year desc,
  min_price_record.departure_month desc;
```